# How to detect packet loss risk in DPDK?

Tags: packet, dpdk

Assume that in a typical DPDK application, a lcore receives streams of packets from queue 0 port 0. After processing, it forwards them to queue 0 port 1. How do we know that we are facing a packet loss risk. I.e. the processing rate is less than income rate and the amount of backlog packets is about to exceed the receive queue size. For example when we receive packets using `rte_eth_rx_burst()` and retrieve MAX possible packets, what can we say? How can we detect packet loss or packet loss risk?

Comment: you have the port counters. http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html see how to get the counters and then you can see drops/errors.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rte_eth_stats_get` you can obtain the interface statistics. The `rte_eth_stats` structure filled by said function contains fields `rx_nombuf` and `imissed` which is what you might be looking for.

Check the [docs](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/structrte__eth__stats.html#a8afc3f87397701e58b218d9dad03be8c) for the `rte_ethdev` for more information.

Comment: What I am looking for is a warning signal for each receive queues to notify the program of an early danger of packet loss. so we could somehow reduce the amount of process we are doing on the packets or drop them in the worst case. the `rte_eth_stats_get()` returns the statistics for the device not for receive queues. What exactly I want is the number of packets inside the receive ring of an specific queue. We use `rte_eth_rx_queue_setup()` to setup the receive queue but we don't have access to the receive ring that has already been set up. If we had, we could have used `rte_ring_count()`.

Comment: When you are processing packets it is useful to know if the amount of backlog packets inside the receive queue is growing or declining. So you could choose how to deal with this changes.

Comment: A ring also has the "watermarking" mechanism which notifies the device in the case the remaining backlogs exceeds a given threshold. It cat be set by `rte_ring_set_water_mark()`. However it doesn't notify the receiver program. I am looking for something like that to signal the calling program.

Comment: I must correct it. `rte_eth_stats_get()` returns statistics per queue. to use is you should first establish a mapping using `rte_eth_dev_set_tx_queue_stats_mapping()`. But I think the maximum mapping allowed is `RTE_ETHDEV_QUEUE_STAT_CNTRS` which is defined in `rte_config.h`. Having the statistics of rx packets (`q_ipackets[i]`) and tx packets (`q_opackets[i]`) for the queue `i`, now we can have the number of existing items int the queue. But isn't there any other convenient way to retrieve the ring counts?